# Can you change the output location for the Randori generated html files?

Tags: javascript, html, randori

I'm creating a new project and I want to customize the location of the generated files from Randori. How can I do this?

Comment: You might want to mention your affiliation with Randori.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Lesson-02: Creating an Initial HTML file & Run Configuration](https://github.com/RandoriAS/randori-plugin-intellij/wiki/Lesson-02%3a-Creating-an-Initial-HTML-file-&-Run-Configuration)

From here you will see how to edit your Randori configuration. You can make the generated output anything you want. However just make sure to update your main html file and point to the correct (customized) generated folder.

Answer (score 0):

One more point on this when you call the launch() method of RandoriBootstrap, you can pass two arguments. The first is whether you want debug mode on or off (debug mode does cache busting) the second is the URL that the class loader will use to find your classes. Should you put things in generatedFoo folder, you need to make sure the RandoriBootstrap knows this.